# Why does python input function swallow chararacters?

Tags: python, macos

Python 2.7.10 and Python 3.5.0 on OS X Yosemite (10.10.5) swallow characters in the output of the input function for me:

`a = 'foo'; a = input('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\nabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\nabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\nabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\nabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\nabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\nabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\nabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\nabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n')`

gives

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
zbcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
yzcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx
```

Surprisingly this does not happen with the print function instead of the input function.

Comment: I can reproduce, but it appears to behave differently in Terminal and iTerm. It's likely unrelated to Python, and more how the underlying terminal handles the long string.

Comment: Not reproducable under Windows and Python 3.4.3 using `cmd.exe` or a powershell as shell.

Comment: Not reproducable on Ubuntu 14.04 w/ Python 3.5 or 2.7 using Python terminal either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely related to the encoding that the Mac OSX Terminal.app uses and the width of the window you are working in.  I was able to recreate your output if the encoding was xterm-256color.  If i made my window as wide as the code line you posted it worked fine.

With a window width of 290 and xterm-256color encoding:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

If I made the window narrower than the line of code and it wrapped it would give similar results to what you are seeing.

With a window width of 60 and xterm-256color encoding:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
mnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
stuvwxyzijklmnopqr 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
yzcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx
```

I was able to change my terminal from xterm-256color to ansi and it didn't matter how wide or narrow my window was the output was always the expected output.

With a window width of 60 and ansi encoding:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

It appears that this isn't related to Python but it related to the window encoding of Mac OSX.